# Magento2: how installation Magento 2 with Nginx on MAMP

Tags: magento2, installation, nginx, mamp

How can I install a Magento2 in Nginx on [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)?

What settings should be made to install Magento2 in Nginx in [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)?

What settings should be made to run Magento2 in Nginx in [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)?

My problem is: in Nginx returns me 404 Not found and in Apache is works.

I have installed the `mcrypt`.

Comment: Isn’t duplicate, I can install Magento 2 in MAMP & MAMP PRO with apache but I can’t install with Ngnix. In your link is other problem. Thnaks anyway.

Comment: this is not about link, use search....

Comment: In your link is a post with missing an extention mcrypt from system, but i don’t have that problem because in my MAMP it works with apache and mcrypt is an extension for apache.

Comment: ??? - In your link is a post with missing an extension mcrypt from the system, but I don’t have that problem because in my MAMP it works with Apache and mcrypt is an extension for Apache.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a duplicate. The topic should be opened back.